# evolution plugin for crm integration via webservices

Tags: python, c, linux, email

I have built a webservice into my companies self developed CRM system that we are in the process of integrating Outlook to the CRM for calendar sync and recording of emails related to clients.

I want to build a plugin for the gnome evolution mail client as I use it for my work mail/calendar as I primarily run Linux.

I am familiar with both C/C++ and to some extent Python but haven't done anything towards either evolution plugins or webservices connections in either so I am looking for some help.

What language would be best to build an evolution plugin that can connect to webservices?

Is there a simple "Hello world" style evolution plugin example somewhere I can use to get  started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the [architecture](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/arch.shtml) of Evolution. Then I would look into [EPlugins](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/eplugins.shtml) and start off with [this](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/developer-doc/eplugin/pt01.html). An example for writing a plugin would be [this](http://www.mumbles-project.org/2007/09/03/tutorial-write-an-evolution-plugin/). You will need some familiarity with XML.

Hope this helps.